# How do we prove that $a+b+\frac12 \geq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ with $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

How do we prove that $$a+b+\frac12 \geq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$$ with $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$?

I tried using Cauchy inequality but doesn't seem to work.
Factor things out also seem impossible or require complex numbers.

Comment: Call $x=\sqrt{a}, y=\sqrt{b}$, the inequality is equivalent to $x^2+y^2+1/2\ge x+y$, which is equivalent to $(x-1/2)^2+(y-1/2)^2\ge 0$.

Comment: Alternative approach - not as elegant as the approach of @Q.Zhang : when $r > 1,$ you have that $r > \sqrt{r}$.  Therefore, without loss of generality, $1 > a,b.$  For any $r$ in the interval $(0,1)$, you have that $r - r^2 = r(1-r).$  So, you have two numbers, $r$ and $(1 - r)$, whose arithmetic mean is $(1/2).$  Based on the idea, that in general $(r + k)(r - k) = r^2 - k^2 < r^2$, you have that the arithmetic mean of two positive numbers is always greater than or equal to the geometric mean.  Therefore, the geometric mean of $(r), (1-r)$ must be $\leq (1/2)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: This implies that the maximum value that can be obtained by $\sqrt{a} - a = \sqrt{a} - \left(\sqrt{a}\right)^2$ is $(1/4).$  Ditto for $\sqrt{b} - b.$

Comment: Please add your exact effort to your question. Then, your question will seem very nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b\geq 0$, then $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}\in\mathbb{R}$ and therefore,
$$\left(\sqrt{a}-\frac12\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{b}-\frac12\right)^2\geq 0$$
$$\implies a+b-(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})+\frac12\geq 0$$
$$\implies a+b+\frac12\geq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$$